# Compare the columns of a dataframe in reverse order and create a new column with the index of the column which has value 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported data from a csv file into my program and then used set_index to set 'rule_id' as index. I used this code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx')
df.set_index(['rule_id'])
```

and the data looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to compare one column with another but in reverse order , for eg; I want to compare 'c' data with 'b' , then compare 'b' with 'a' and so on and create another column after the comparison which contains the index of the column where the value was zero. If both the columns have value 0 , then Null should be updated in the new column and if both the comparison values are other than 0 , then also Null should be updated in the new column. 
The result should look like this:

[image]

I am not able to write the code of how should I approach this problem, if you guys could help me , that would be great.

Edit: A minor edit. I have imported the data from an excel which looks like this , this is just a part of data , there are multiple columns:

[image]

Then I used pivot_table to manipulate the data as per my requirement using this code:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'rule_id' , columns = ['date'], values = 'rid_fc', fill_value = 0)
```

and my data looks like this now:

[image]

Now I want to compare one column with another but in reverse order , for eg; I want to compare '2019-04-25 16:36:32' data with '2019-04-25 16:29:05' , then compare '2019-04-25 16:29:05' with '2019-04-25 16:14:14' and so on and create another column after the comparison which contains the index of the column where the value was zero. If both the columns have value 0 , then Null should be updated in the new column and if both the comparison values are other than 0 , then also Null should be updated in the new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use numpy - compare shifted values with `logical_and` and set new columns by range created by `np.arange` with swap order and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with DatFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[0,0,0],
         'b':[7,0,2],
         'c':[6,1,2],
})

#change order of array
x = df.values[:, ::-1]
#compare for equal 0 and and not equal 0
a = np.logical_and(x[:, 1:] == 0, x[:, :-1] != 0)
#create range from top to 0
b = np.arange(a.shape[1]-1, -1, -1)
#new columns names
c = [f'comp{i+1}' for i in range(x.shape[1] - 1)]
#set values by boolean array a and set values
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(a,  b[None, :], np.nan), columns=c, index=df.index)
print (df1)

   comp1  comp2
0    NaN    0.0
1    1.0    NaN
2    NaN    0.0
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael , I am getting this error when I use your code: 'columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['comp1', 'comp2', 'comp3'], dtype='object') ' and also you have used np.where() and in that you have used the column names as 'a' , 'b' , 'c' but I just used them for readibility purpose only , my original columns looks like this: 2019-04-25 16:14:14

Comment: @vesuvius - Error means there are already columns before, so then is necessary `df = df.join(df1, lsuffix='_new')`

Comment: Yeah , my bad , sorry. But I am still not getting the result I want , I am getting 0 and Null everywhere and three comp columns too as oppose to your result @jezrael

Comment: @vesuvius - So if need compre only 3 columns change `x = df.values` to `x = df[['a','b','c']].values` - specify columns names in list

Comment: I got the result but I have used 'a' , 'b' ,'c' for readilibily purpose only and I have multiple columns which looks like this:  2019-04-25 16:14:14 , so it won't be feasible for me to mention the columns everytime , can you suggest some other alterations , sorry for extending it.

Comment: @vesuvius - first question - need working with only 3 columns or many columns?

Comment: I have multiple columns which looks like the combination of date and timestamp

Comment: @vesuvius - So maybe not sure if understand what need, is possible add 2-3 new columns with exected output and columns like need in your data? Because maybe soemthing wrong in my solution, but not sure how the best test it.

Comment: I have updated my question @jezrael , this is my original data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194118/discussion-between-jezrael-and-vesuvius).

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can try with:

```
d={i:e for e,i in enumerate(df.columns)}
m1=df[['c','b']]
m2=df[['b','a']]
```

---

```
df['comp1']=m1.eq(0).dot(m1.columns).map(d)
m3=m2.eq(0).dot(m2.columns)
m3.loc[m3.str.len()!=1]=np.nan
df['comp2']=m3.map(d)
print(df)
```

---

```
         a  b  c  comp1  comp2
rule_id                       
51234    0  7  6    NaN    0.0
53219    0  0  1    1.0    NaN
56195    0  2  2    NaN    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of this code snippet. I did not have time to perfect it with loops etc. so please make the change as per requirements.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
print(df.head())
   a  b  c
0  0  7  6
1  0  0  1
2  0  2  2

cp = df.copy()
cp[cp != 0] = 1
cp['comp1'] = cp['a'] + cp['b']
cp['comp2'] = cp['b'] + cp['c']

# Logic
cp = cp.replace([0, 1, 2], [1, np.nan, 0])
cp[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]

# Results
print(cp.head())
   a  b  c  comp1  comp2
0  0  7  6    NaN    0.0
1  0  0  1    1.0    NaN
2  0  2  2    NaN    0.0
```

Comment: Hi @skillsmuggler , I have multiple columns , so it won't be feasible for me to declare a new column with the name of 'comp' every time. Can you suggest something else , I am thinking of using columns=lambda x: 'comp{}'.format(x+1) to get rid of this problem.